# EF 6: Is it possible to move an entity from a parent to a child, while keeping a reference to the parent in the moved entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framwork 6.1 (Code First) for an aquarium game. In that game the *Player* can purchase *AquariumObjects* (e.g. stones, plants,..), which will first go into the *Player*'s inventory (which is just a List of AquariumObjects in *Player* ).
From there, the player can drag the AquariumObjects into one of her aquariums. This is where the troubles starts: I would like to keep a ForeignKey / Navigation Property to *Player* in the *AquariumObject* entity, even thoug i remove it from the inventory List. In my first approach, *Player* was even part of AquariumObject's composite key. However, when i tried to move the AquariumObject from the ObjectsInInventory List, i get this error upon db.SaveChanges():
***"Adding a relationship with an entity which is in the Deleted state is not allowed."***

So the main problem here seems to be, that EF will delete the entity and null out the FK column in AquariumObject when i call

```
player.ObjectsInInventory.Remove(dataObject);
```

...even though i tried to manually restore that reference before calling db.SaveChanges(). I tried to do so by calling this:

```
targetAquarium.AquariumObjects.Add(dataObject);
targetAquarium.Player = ownerPlayer;
aquariumObject.Player = ownerPlayer;
```

In the debugger everything looks healthy though, and all the references to *Player* seem to be intact.

When i dropped the constraint of *Player* being part of the composite key in *AquariumObject* (and just trying to keep it as a Navigation property), i get another error:
***The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted***

So it seems to be impossible to move an entity to a child, while keeping a reference to the parent in the moved entity?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! Here's my current model:

```
public class Player
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid PlayerGuid { get; set; }

    public List<Aquarium> Aquariums { get; set; }

    public List<AquariumObject> ObjectsInInventory { get; set; }
}


public class AquariumObject
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("Player")]    
    public Guid PlayerId { get; set; }

    public Player Player { get; set; }


    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int InstanceId { get; set; }    
}


public class Aquarium
{

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("Player")]
    public Guid PlayerGuid { get; set; }

    public Player Player { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int AquariumId { get; set; }

    public List<AquariumObject> AquariumObjects { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `player.ObjectsInInventory.Remove(dataObject);` you are deleting the AquariumObject from the database because the AquariumObject can not exist without a reference to a Player (since it's part of the primary key).  If you remove it from the primary key **and also change it to a nullable field** (which is the reason you got the second error) you should be able to remove from `Player.ObjectsInInventory` and add to `Aquarium.AquariumObjects`.

Having said that, my suggestion would be to simplify the model (simpler to me, at least :-) ) like the following.  Additionally, in my experience, it's easier to name the primary keys in the format of [TableName]Id.  EF can find them without any extra configuration (ForiegnKey attributes).  Lastly, I believe the navigation properties need to be marked as virtual:

```
public class Player
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid PlayerId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Aquarium> Aquariums { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AquariumObject> AquariumObjects{ get; set; }
}

public class AquariumObject
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AquariumObjectId { get; set; }

    public int? AquariumId { get; set; }

    public virtual Aquarium { get; set; }

    public Guid PlayerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Player { get; set; }
}

public class Aquarium
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int AquariumId { get; set; }

    public Guid PlayerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Player Player { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AquariumObject> AquariumObjects { get; set; }
}
```

Using this model, it would change the concept so that every `AquariumObject` would be attached to a player, and possibly to an Aquarium.  If it is attached to an aquarium it wouldn't be "in the inventory", and vice versa, if `AquariumId` was null, it would be.

So, the `Player.AquariumObjects` would include all objects under the players control.  `Player.AquariumObjects.Where(e => !e.AquariumId.HasValue)` would include only the objects that are in inventory.  And `Player.AquariumObjects.Where(e => e.AquariumId == 1)` would include everything in an Aquarium with an id of 1.

Also, aquarium is a weird word if you say (or write) it enough, heh.

Comment: Wyatt, thanks alot for your suggestions! I'll happily fall back to your DataModel, but first i'll try to mark the "Player" Foreign Key in AquariumObject as nullable, as you suggested. I'm a FluentAPI noob, so here's what i tried, but it's still marked as "NOT NULL" in the table definition :/  Any idea what's going wrong?
`modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
                .HasMany(p => p.AquariumObjectsInInventory)
                .WithOptional()
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.PlayerId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);`

PS: "aquarium aquarium aquarium!" :D

Comment: @ponx And did you also make AquariumObject.PlayerGuid nullable as well: `public Guid? PlayerGuid`  or `public Guid? PlayerId` if you renamed it.

Comment: Wyatt, you are a life-saver! I didn't know about the questionmark as the "nullable" marker.  It's working now! Thank you so much!  (i'd click your reputation sky-high if i could)   cheers and thanks again, ponx

Comment: @ponx, glad it helped.  :)